# How would react a medieval magic world to the arrival of an Interstellar colony?

Tags: science-based, society, magic, space-colonization, civilization

**Edit** (I rephrase the question a bit to try to  not made it opinion based)

A space colony comes to a planet who is pretty similar to how fantasy's worlds tend to be represented.
The space colony is 44% formed by "humans" only 8% of these still look like classic humans, the others evolved due to the environment of different planets, among other things, this colony is made up of different sub-species of humans that have been separated for a long time by colonizing different planets without developing the technology to communicate efficiently, took light years, and using ships that traveled 94% speed of light, is technically recent that the technologies of warp drive and quantum communication were developed, the other 56% of the ship is divided into 33% of robots that fall under the definition of "individuals" another 14% are animals that were modified to be intelligent, such as chimpanzees or an octopus, and the last 9% are totally alien species that were associated with humanity. 
The leaders of this colony are a group of "humans" an I.A and an extraterrestrial. 
The population is about 930,000

They came to this curious planet, they are one of many colonizing / scout ships, but due to bad luck, a solar flare damages their warp propeller and the communication system with the others ships without any repairs, and they send a smaller ship to the planet, entering accidentally in a dramatically way in what should be the medium of a typical battle between the dark stereotypical army and the hero's army, how would they react to this? I mean;

-there is or was any protocol if a third group of non-hostile individuals appears from nowhere in the middle of the battle?

The magical world has, well, magic, is capable of doing things that break the laws of physics and logic but the more powerful a type of spell it requires a kind of "price" at the level of the soul, so they cannot only say "adabracadabra" and achieve everything, not everyone can be a wizard. 
The dominant race of this world are also human, or at least they look like them, there are beings with magical properties but they are more essential and not variables things, this magical world has literally gods, in fact, that planet was made by them, they are beings of more than 3 dimensions, but not everyone has seen them, the technological level of the cultures in this world do not yet develop the metal molding, literature on the other hand if it exists, a religion predominates with values ​​similar to the Christians but polytheist, even when there are a lot of magical beings, and some gods, like In real life, some cultures invented more, the mayor cultures of the world do not like the science or the scientific method, because can go against some of his mystic and religious beliefs, the don't like even some complex machines when it take away the place to things that by almost obligatory tradition are carried out "magically". 
Of course, there are individuals, and groups of individuals that go against this thought, especially in the equivalent of this world to classical Greece, but they are minorities and mostly not so well seen, but, outside that, i would say that the world culturally speaking, also outside Christianity taking the world ahead of time, is mostly similar to how the world was in 500-600 BC

I imagine one of the main civilizations have the aesthetics of the Celts (only the aesthetics and customs that do not contradict their religion)
In this magical world there are other intelligent creatures such as ogres and elves and things like that, even many of the animals that are magical are very intelligent, some as much as a human. There are also "normal" animals btw

The interaction between the visitors and the locals I imagine something ... chaotic at the beginning, a division of the colony will become violent and will want to take the planet by force, and the mother-ship have highly advanced weapons and is very well armed, while another part oppose to them and helped stop them, taking all this into account:

-Is there any historical interaction that is similar to this?
-Or are there different examples that I should take into consideration? I understand that surely there was not an encounter with all these characteristics in real life, but surely there were different cultural clashes, with characteristics similar to those I said

I would not mind hearing suggestions on how you think they would react realistically, too

I should mention that my intention is that the colony is a lot of light years away from another habitable planet, and the technology to warp the space is damaged, so they must stay in there.
And the gods are not going to do anything about anyone, literally.

There is a image about the time period i want to take inspiration
[image: 500 AC]

Comment: Hello Invasor. I think, as it is phrased now, your question is primarily opinion based, as well as mostly up to you and your specific setting. Perhaps a re-wording would make things better - example, asking for historical "similar" events and general tendency, etc.

Comment: I don't see how asking "How would X react" could be anything but opinion based. There is no *right* or *wrong* answer to the question and that makes it off topic. Please read more about it in the [help], especially [how to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what questions to avoid](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkover and many others.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this is my own suggestions based on opinion and personal experience but hopefully you can take something helpful from it.

1. Check out Gate: Jieitai Kano Chi nite, Kaku Tatakaeri, might be of some use as a point of reference for how it could possibly go, though the scenario in this show is different from your described scenario. In the show, there is both an initial non-pacifist first contact as well as pacifist first contacts. From this if you don't want to look at the show in case of overlap, remember that there will be multiple first contacts as communication isn't immediate and worldwide (unless there is some magical forms of communication). The inhabitants would either believe the technology to be powerful sorcery or believe they are from a far away land on their world.

   2. The reaction when attacked by the rebels would depend on the culture of the interstellar travellers. Would they respond in kind, obliterating them with the far superior technologies or even battle due to magic balancing the difference? Would they run to avoid potential casualties either for their own sake or the sake of the rebels? Would they be offended or take pride in being considered a worthy adversary for war? Also, if it is a small party of the travelers being attacked by rebels, it will depend on the individuals' personalities and not just culture. With that said, the personality of the leaders will matter on a larger scale. Also, will the AI onboard understand the properties of magic or will it be too much for them to handle and therefore miscalculate things such as battle outcomes and strategies?
   3. See point 2. 
      With the dominant race being human, don't forget to remember that only 8% of the travelers will be similar to them, with the other percentage of the traveling human population being different to the local populace of human/human-like natives.
      Also will they be able to speak to eachother? Even if you have them share the same language or have some translator device, there may be phraseology the travelers won't understand and visa versa.

Hope this helps ;)